# Leaflet and Tangram conctenated into a single script file

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to concat leaflet and tangram source codes into a single script file using grunt to include it in an api which I am trying to make based on both leaflet and tangram. If I include the leaflet and tangram js files using different script tags in the html, the code works perfectly. But If i concat them using grunt and use a single script file I get the following error:

> ReferenceError: window is not defined

The example code which I tried to run is as follows:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([12.96,77.58],14);
var layer = Tangram.leafletLayer({
scene: '../scene/scene.yaml',
      });
layer.addTo(map);
var marker = L.marker([12.96,77.58]).addTo(map);
```

This is a simple code to setup the map with a scene.yaml file and then add a marker to it. This code runs perfectly if separate script tags are used for both leaflet and tangram in that order. But the same code gives the above mentioned error when a single script tag is used with the concatenated script file with leaflet on the top and tangram following it.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40109909/leaflet-and-tangram-conctenated-into-a-single-script-file